# Unable to Capture and verify error validation messages in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to verify the error validation messages for the following [site](https://tenoapp.com/registerSchool).
After clicking on submit validation error messages are displayed for all fields.
I tried with the code:

```
List<WebElement> errormsg = driver.findElements(By.className("errorValidation"));
System.out.println(errormsg);
```

It's not retrieving the error messages, it errors out instead:

```
[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (c997bfe2-8c35-4b00-abf9-74a96437020c)] -> >class name: errorValidation], [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (c997bfe2->8c35-4b00-abf9-74a96437020c)] -> class name: errorValidation], [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (c997bfe2-8c35-4b00-abf9-74a96437020c)] -> class name: >errorValidation], [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (c997bfe2-8c35-4b00-abf9->74a96437020c)] -> class name: errorValidation], [[FirefoxDriver:
```

Answer (score 0):

`driver.findElements()` does not return an array of error message strings, it returns an array of Selenium WebElements. Each of them has a text value, which you have to fetch from each WebElement:

```
System.out.println(errormsg[0].gettext());
System.out.println(errormsg[1].gettext());
...
```

(I do my Selenium tests in C#, where there is a property called "Text", but I think in Java you have this method called gettext().)

Answer (score 0):

try like this:
i have run this code and its work nice.

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;

public class stackTest {
static WebDriver driver = null;
public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException{

     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


        driver.get("https://tenoapp.com/registerSchool");

        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#submitRegForm")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);

        String[] urerrormsg = { "School name can't be blank", 
                "Number of students can't be blank", 
                "Board can't be blank", 
                "First name can't be blank",
                "Last name can't be blank",
                "Designation can't be blank",
                "Mobile number can't be blank",
                "Password can't be blank",
                "Confirm password can't be blank"};

        List<WebElement> erromsgsize =  driver.findElements(By.className("errorValidation"));
        System.out.println("***** "+erromsgsize.size());
        int i = 0;
        for (WebElement errormsg : erromsgsize) {

            System.out.println("**** "+errormsg.getText());
            if(errormsg.getText().equals("")){
                continue;
            }


            else
                Assert.assertTrue(errormsg.getText().equals(urerrormsg[i]));
            i++;
        }  

        //Close the browser
        driver.quit();

}

}
```

Comment: actually, u can do this more smartly by using arraylist...than no need to hard code ur error messages...try to do it by using arraylist.... :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code:

```
List<WebElement> el = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='errorValidation']")
```

User TestNg Assert function like:

```
Assert.assertTrue(el.get(0).equals("School name can't be blank");
Assert.assertTrue(el.get(1).equals("Number of students can't be blank");
```

Similar for other fields you can apply

Hope this will work.

Thanks
Sadik

Comment: By using AssertTrue() its showing compilation error

Comment: Are you using TestNg ?

Comment: Please check that you are using . in place of , also I updated in above code